# How to stop adding duplicate rows in java JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, project

```java
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) /Button Click/
 {                                         
        

        DefaultTableModel dt=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();  /Table Model /

        String tn=jname.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String jf=jfrom.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String jt=jto.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String jm=jtime.getText();
        
         String Data[]={tn,jf,jt,jm};                  
         dt.addRow(Data);
}
```

This is my code for pressing ADD Button.
when i press add the duplicate values are also added in new row.
i want only new values to be stored in new row and want to show the error if the same values are inputted.

Can someone kindly help me with this? will there be a loop or some function?
Please Help!

Comment: Iterate through existing cells and test if they contain rows you're attempting to add

Comment: I've tried looping them but i am maybe doing wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: i ran a while loop to end of table like and then compared the strings. i can't do it. Can you tell me?

Comment: Try keeping a static array with all the data added. You can go through the array to see if there are duplicates before adding to the table.

Comment: @Alias but how? can you just show me the syntax? I'm sorry for bothering but its just I'm new to java...

Comment: @AliasCartellano, the TableModel already holds all the data. There is no need to duplicate the data by also holding it in an Array.

Comment: so what's the solution, do you know? @camickr

Comment: Anyone knows anything...??